# Valid jQuery scripts not loading in production mode

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Having some troubles with my site in production mode. Getting some errors from the jQuery scripts so it's not loading. Thought jQuery.noConflict(); could solve it, but it failed me! Been trying so many things now so I'm open for any suggestions to solutions or debugging.

Heres my errors:

```
Uncaught controls.js requires including script.aculo.us' effects.js library
/#about:30Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'
/#about:12Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'
```

The one who solves it gets a gold star! Thank you ;(

Comment: Are you using Prototype and jQuery together on purpose?

Comment: @gg_s Hm, no not really. Never meant to use prototype.. Don't know how to remove it though, hmm..

Comment: The origin for this could be that when i move it in production mode, it was first wrong version of rails on the server, so then I tried to change it to 3.0.10 from 3.1.1, but mean while I did this, the support upgraded the rails on my server, so then I had to redo all changes. And now it seems lite it includes prototype stil..

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to fix the first error before tackling subsequent errors (since they may come from a cascading failure).  According your your uncaught exception, you have a script called "controls.js" that requires the script.aculo.us library to be loaded on the page in order to work.  Download the library from here [Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/downloads) put it into your web directory, and include it BEFORE controls.js loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/location/to/scriptaculous.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Gold Star ? Ok
I had a similar problem. Your problem is not jQuery.noConflict(); neither is it prototype js but rather that you did not add everything there is to to the noconflict

1 - Fist of all align every other librairie that does not use jquery ex:

```
<script src="js/scriptaculous/lib/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/scriptaculous/src/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
 <script language="javascript" src="js/protoplasm/protoplasm.js"></script>

 <script>
        Protoplasm.use('rte').transform('textarea.richeditor');
</script>
```

2 - After that insert your jquery file and directly followed up with noconflict before any other library or code that uses jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.noConflict();

    </script>
```

3 - And MOST IMPORTANTLY and this is where you are missing the point
Open each and every other javascript code you have as js that uses jquery like Bootstrap.min.js or app.js and if you find jquery inside, then put on top of the code, at the very begin of the file (ex at the begining of bootstrap.min.js) the following code

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

4- At the very end of the code (ex at the end of bootstrap.min.js) put the following code

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

});
```

5 - Put also every other code using jquery in your page between another

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    });
```

As you can see jquery noconflict alone is not enough. You really have to add those codes everywhere jquery is being used even in external file if you do not want any interference

You may face some few error in controls.js with firebug but all your codes will work. Even when you remove control.js, as long as scriptaculous.js is on your page, Firebug will always give you and error like TypeError: this.element is null controls.js but all your code will be working perfectly.

Please, do not forget the Gold star. Thanks