# jQuery errors and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940).

and struck at step `12`.

Getting these 4 errors on console:

```
Uncaught controls.js requires including script.aculo.us' effects.js library<br/>
Uncaught ReferenceError: Effect is not defined<br/>
Uncaught ReferenceError: Prototype is not defined<br/>
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

The article is from 2011, using a very old version of Rails.

Rails 4 is not provided with scriptaculous anymore.

You have two options:

1. *download and enable scriptaculous in your Rails application*;
2. *adapt scriptaculous' functions to use jquery instead*.

It seem it is a valid jQuery code.

Have you included scriptaculous on your application?

If so, can you try this?

[Valid jQuery scripts not loading in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253977/valid-jquery-scripts-not-loading-in-production-mode)

Comment: I am using rails 4.2.4 ..so how to adapt jquery code?? I have included all the jquery libraries which were relevant

Comment: i have edited the answer. can you check it, please? :)

Comment: Yes I have already downloaded scriptaculous file and it is in my folder assets/javascript ..do i need to place it somewhere else also ?? do i need to include that scriptaculous file in my views/layout/application.html.erb ?? or application.js file

Comment: you need to add it to your application.js file.

Comment: 1. move it to your 'vendor/assets/javascripts' folder.

Comment: 2. add it to your application.js using 'require': //= require scriptaculous

Comment: When I am viewing the page source so control.js file is coming up and scriptaculous file is coming down...

Comment: probably the require of 'scriptaculous' is after the require of 'control' or after require_tree. try putting the require scriptaculous first.

Comment: now you need to download prototype to your 'vendor/assets/javascripts' and add it to your 'application.js' file, before the require_tree. :)

Comment: I have downloaded prototype file and place in javascript directory and included it before require_tree also included effects.js before require_tree Now I am getting 3 errors but they are all same  1)Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function

Comment: see the link on my answer. it looks like conflict with jQuery.

Comment: hey I have written  $.noConflict(); in my application .js file now  I am getting only two errors 1) Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function  2 ) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of null

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand what change I have to make

Comment: try putting jQuery.noConflict(), instead of $.noConflict();

Comment: I have Jquery.noConflict() in my application.js folder and now popup is loading but 1 error is still coming 1) Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function also no form is coming in that popup

Comment: THis is my application.js file   //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require prototype
//= require scriptaculous
//= require effects
//= require_tree .
// Add following lines.
//= require controls
//= require social-share-button
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$( ".share a" ).bind("click", function()
{ 
var a = this;
$("#invitation_form").attr("title", "Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others" );

Comment: $("#ui-dialog-title-invitation_form").text("Share '" + $(a).attr("folder_name") + "' with others"); 
    $("#folder_id").val($(a).attr("folder_id"));
    $( "#invitation_form" ).dialog({
     height: 300,
     width: 600,
     modal: true,
     buttons: {
     "Share": function() {
       var post_url = $("#invitation_form form").attr("action");
       $.post(post_url,$("#invitation_form form").serialize(), null, "script"); 
       return false;
      },
      Cancel: function() {
       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
     },

Comment: close: function() {

     }
    });
    
    return false;
   });

 });